# Ansible advanced filters ternary

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Is it possible to achaive somehow equivalent of `tenary` filter with mix of strings and variables at the same time? I'm thinking of argument substitution.

i.e.

```
  - name: using custom_fact
    shell: "add enet-connection {{item.0.profile_name}} {{ custom_fact is defined | tenary("Speed={{item.1.ansible_facts.custom_fact_key}}", '')}}"
    with_together:
      - "{{enet}}"
      - "{{custom_fact.results}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I guess you're using the te**r**nary filter)

Once you're in a `{{ }}` section, you're writing direct code: no need to use curly brace again for other variables:

```
- name: using custom_fact
  shell: "add enet-connection {{item.0.profile_name}} {{ item.1.ansible_facts.custom_fact_key is defined | ternary('Speed=' + item.1.ansible_facts.custom_fact_key, '')}}"
  with_together:
    - "{{enet}}"
    - "{{custom_fact.results}}"
```

Comment: The only problem is that it still returns `Speed=` if the `custom_fact is not define`  I has hoping for just `None` so I would get `add enet-connection profile_1` rather than `add enet-connection profile_1 Speed=`

Comment: Are you sure it's the `custom_facts` that need to be defined? In the case it's not, your task will fail as it's trying to access `custom_facts.results`. Shouldn't your test be on `item.1.ansible_facts.custom_fact_key`?

Comment: sorry my fault when copy-paste yes I'm trying to do `add enet-connection {{item.0.profile_name}} {{ item.1.ansible_facts.custom_fact_key is defined | ternary('Speed=' + item.1.ansible_facts.custom_fact_key, '')}}` however I don't want to get anything when `item.1.ansible_facts.custom_fact_key is not defined`

Comment: Hmm I found the problem, the `item.1.ansible_facts.custom_fact_key = ""` which evaluates to **defined** :(

Comment: But when `item.1.ansible_facts.custom_fact_key` is not defined you still get `Speed=<empty>`? It would means that the variable IS defined, but empty. You may change your test to `item.1.ansible_facts.custom_fact_key | bool | ...`

Comment: yes, becasue sometimes the I may have an undefined variable (i.e. optional argument in the "upstream" which is not being passed to the vars: dictionary) I have a `set_fact: {'custom_fact_key': {{optional_var|default('')}}}` at this for Ansible treats the `custom_fact_key=""` as **empty string** which unfortunately is defined. Anyway thank you for your help with dropping the **{}** and adding the **+** I'm few steps closer to the solution :)

Comment: it should be `with_together` instead `with_twogether`?

Comment: Right! Fixed it. Thanks.